# assert(true) warns of signed/unsigned mismatch

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, assert, suppress-warnings

Visual Studio 2008, debug build.  This line of C++

```
assert(true);
```

causes the complaint

```
warning C4365: 'argument' : conversion from 'long' to 'unsigned int', signed/unsigned mismatch
```

The warning persists when replacing `true` with any (useful) boolean expression, even with `1ul`.

FYI, the compiler's file `assert.h` is:

```
#define assert(_Expression) (void)( (!!(_Expression)) || (_wassert(_CRT_WIDE(#_Expression), _CRT_WIDE(__FILE__), __LINE__), 0) )
extern "C" _CRTIMP void __cdecl _wassert(_In_z_ const wchar_t * _Message, _In_z_ const wchar_t *_File, _In_ unsigned _Line);
```

How can this warning be cleanly suppressed, without suppressing *all* C4365's?  Is it the fault of `__LINE__`??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The bug report explains it very well](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/792554/assert-macro-in-assert-h-causes-compiler-warning-c4365):

> This issue occurs because `__LINE__` is of type long, and the assert
>   macro passes `__LINE__` as an argument to the _wassert function, which
>   expects an unsigned int. When not compiling with `/ZI`, `__LINE__` is a
>   constant expression, so the compiler can statically determine that the
>   conversion to unsigned int will result in the same value. When
>   compiling with `/ZI`, `__LINE__` is not a constant expression, so the
>   compiler cannot statically determine that the conversion will result
>   in the same value and it issues warning C4365.

It also gives a workaround:

> As a workaround for this issue, I would recommend #undefing assert in
>   your source code, and re-#define-ing it, using the same definition as
>   in `<assert.h>`, but with a cast to suppress the warning.

Note that this bug seems to have been fixed starting from MSVC2015.